# A naughty, naughty riddle (take that, NSA!)

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking

> Feeling lucky, punk? 
>   Go on, ogle me, why don't ya? 
>   But don't dare ask me for a quickie 
>   Or else I'll just taunt ya 
>   Just tell me what I want to hear 
>   That you're a spy who loves me 
>   If I reply with R&B and friendly service 
>   You'll know that you have me

A complete solution should address the following questions:

1. Who am I?
2. What was my reply to your amorous advances?
3. What was the method prescribed by the riddle to arrive at the solution?

---

**Edit:** question_asker's answer is correct and I have accepted it. However, an unfortunate thing happened that I didn't anticipate and which spoiled a part of the riddle. As a result, the accepted solution is still slightly different from my intended one, though there was no way question_asker could know this. It's still possible to solve the riddle (for example, question_asker solved it despite this apparent flaw), but if you plan to try it, keep in mind the following small

hint:

> Lines 3-4 of the riddle don't make sense anymore, so you might want to just ignore them. But in the future they may become important again, in which case you would need to take them into account - I can't predict whether this would happen.

And here is a more complete explanation of the problem (contains a big spoiler):

> My idea was that to solve the riddle you would need to google a certain phrase (as explained in question_asker's answer, and choose the first result THAT IS NOT FROM WIKIPEDIA. Lines 3-4 provide the clue that tells you to ignore results from Wikipedia (or to include "-wiki" in your search phrase). The search phrase was designed so that the first search result that would be displayed would actually be to the Wikipedia page for the film "The Spy Who Loved Me" if "-wiki" was not included, which would have been a small red herring that makes the riddle slightly more challenging. However, what happened was that overnight Google promoted the non-Wikipedia search result to first place (maybe because I clicked it several times when designing the riddle), thus ruining the effect.

Comment: The riddle becomes easier if you 'Go on, ogle me'? =D

Comment: @Alex I can neither confirm nor deny this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So I tried to

> **Go** [on,] **ogle** [me] the phrase "I'm a spy who loves you"

and I

> **[felt] lucky**, so I chose the first result

which was

> [a video for a song of (nearly) that same title](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jArxD7n7Xk0), by Rob Bender, from ***R***[**&**]**B**'s Goodie Garden, and the lyrics to which are [here](https://robbendermusic.bandcamp.com/track/im-the-spy-who-loves-you-2) (I can't listen at the moment)

The above, to the best of my understanding, addresses point 3, and the third chunk of spoilertext addresses point 2, with point 1 *possibly* being answered by the bolded text in the first chunk of spoilertext (I am the least sure of this last bit).